# ORA-04091 Error when creating trigger

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger that will take the amount of blood donated for a blood bank and add that to the current quantity for that specific blood type. I can compile the trigger without any issues. However when I run some entries, I get three errors, ORA-04091, ORA-06512 and ORA-04088. It says the table is being mutated so the trigger cant access it but I use after insert in the trigger so shouldn't the table already be inserted? Any suggestions would be great, the professor didn't really cover triggers much.

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger addBloodCount
after insert on Donations
for each row
when(new.donationID is not null AND new.donorID is not null AND    new.bloodCode is not null AND new.donationDate is not null AND new.amountDonated         is not null)
declare
add_amount INTEGER;
begin
select amountDonated into add_amount from Donations;
update Blood
set quantity = Blood.quantity + add_amount
where bloodCode =:new.bloodCode;
end;
/
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Address (
addressID INTEGER NOT NULL,
street VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
state VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
zip INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (addressID));


CREATE TABLE Donor (
donorID INTEGER NOT NULL,
fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
sex VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
addressID INTEGER NOT NULL,
DOB DATE NOT NULL,
phoneNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (donorID));


CREATE TABLE Donations (
donationID INTEGER NOT NULL,
donorID INTEGER NOT NULL,
bloodCode INTEGER NOT NULL,
donationDate DATE NOT NULL,
amountDonated INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (donationID));


CREATE TABLE Blood (
bloodCode INTEGER NOT NULL,
bloodType VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
bloodPrice DECIMAL NOT NULL,
quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (bloodCode));


CREATE TABLE BloodOrder (
orderID INTEGER NOT NULL,
bloodCode INTEGER NOT NULL,
hospitalID INTEGER NOT NULL,
amountOrdered INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (orderID));


CREATE TABLE Hospital (
hospitalID INTEGER NOT NULL,
hospitalName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
addressID INTEGER NOT NULL,
phoneNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (hospitalID));


alter table Donor
add (constraint addressID_fk foreign key (addressID)
references Address(addressID));

alter table Donations
add (constraint donorID_fk foreign key (donorID)
references Donor(donorID));

alter table Donations
add (constraint bloodCode_fk foreign key (bloodCode)
references Blood(bloodCode));

alter table bloodOrder
add (constraint bloodCode_fk2 foreign key (bloodCode)
references Blood(bloodCode));

alter table bloodOrder
add (constraint hospitalID_fk foreign key (hospitalID)
references Hospital(hospitalID));

alter table Hospital
add (constraint addressID_fk2 foreign key (addressID)
references Address(addressID));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is being caused by this statement:

```
select amountDonated into add_amount from Donations;
```

In short, you cannot reference values being inserted directly. You need to use :NEW instead. Re-writing the trigger as follows should work:

```
create or replace trigger addBloodCount
after insert on Donations
for each row
when(new.donationID is not null AND new.donorID is not null AND new.bloodCode is not null AND new.donationDate is not null AND new.amountDonated is not null)
begin
update Blood
set quantity = quantity + :new.amountDonated
where bloodCode =:new.bloodCode;
end;
/
```

Statement

```
when(new.donationID is not null AND new.donorID is not null AND new.bloodCode is not null AND new.donationDate is not null AND new.amountDonated is not null)
```

is probably not needed since you already have NOT NULL constraints set in all these columns.